# the SSHClient.Close() method of paramiko need to wait?

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko

everyone.

I use the parmiko with python 3.3.3 x64 on window 7 x64, the following is my code, and the strange is I need add time.sleep(0.01) for delay before using client.close() to end the session. Otherwise, a lot of processes will be existed in the SSH host and could not end automatically.

Could anyone do me a favor to explain these?
The paramiko used for python3:
(https://travis-ci.org/nischu7/paramiko)

Here is the steps for repeat:
A)remove the time.sleep(0.01) before client.close() and run the script

B)type the password for the SSH host

C)type the first command, for example: ls -la

D)type the command very frequently, for example, keep pressing the up-arrow and enter alternatively very fast with several times

E)when using ps -ef | grep dropbear (the SSH server, I have not tested about OpenSSH), a lot of processes exists

F) type exit and Ctrl + Z to terminate the script

G)keep the time.sleep(0.01) before client.close() and run the script again

H)do the above steps of B, C, D,  then check with ps -ef | grep dropbear again, only one SSH process will generate by this script.

and here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty

import _thread
import time

from paramiko import SSHClient, Transport, AutoAddPolicy, WarningPolicy
import getpass      

def start(client):
    try :
        client.connect(hostname='127.0.0.1', port=22, username='ubuntu', password=pw)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        client.close()
        print(e)
        return False

def check(client,outqueue):
    while start(client):
        outqueue.put("Command to run: ")
        cmd = input()
        if cmd == "exit":
            client.close()
            break
        chan = client.get_transport().open_session()
        outqueue.put("running '%s'" % cmd)
        chan.exec_command(cmd)
        while True:
            if chan.recv_ready():
                data = chan.recv(4096).decode('ascii')
                outqueue.put("recv:\n%s" %data)
            if chan.recv_stderr_ready():
                error = chan.recv_stderr(4096).decode('ascii')
                outqueue.put("error:\n%s" %error)
            if chan.exit_status_ready():
                exitcode = chan.recv_exit_status()
                outqueue.put("exit status: %s" %exitcode)
                #print('close s')
                #print(client.close())
                time.sleep(0.01)
                client.close()
                #print('close e')
                #time.sleep(0.05)
                break

def reader(outqueue):
    while True:
        while outqueue.qsize():
            try:
                data = outqueue.get()
                if data:
                    print(data)
            except Excetpiton as e:
                print(e)
                #continue
        #time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__=='__main__':
    pw = getpass.getpass()
    client = SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(WarningPolicy())
    #client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())    
    outqueue = Queue()

    r = Thread(target=reader,args=(outqueue,))
    r.daemon = True
    r.start()

    t = Thread(target=check,args=(client,outqueue,))
    #t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a mistake, I start the client more than one time, so solved by the following:

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty

import _thread
import time

from paramiko import SSHClient, Transport, AutoAddPolicy, WarningPolicy
import getpass      

def start(client):
    try :
        client.connect(hostname='127.0.0.1', port=22, username='ubuntu', password=pw)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        client.close()
        print(e)
        return False

def check(client,outqueue): 
    while True:
        outqueue.put("Command to run: ")
        cmd = input()
        if cmd == "exit":
            client.close()
            break
        chan = client.get_transport().open_session()
        outqueue.put("running '%s'" % cmd)
        chan.exec_command(cmd)
        while True:
            if chan.recv_ready():
                data = chan.recv(4096).decode('ascii')
                outqueue.put("recv:\n%s" %data)
            if chan.recv_stderr_ready():
                error = chan.recv_stderr(4096).decode('ascii')
                outqueue.put("error:\n%s" %error)
            if chan.exit_status_ready():
                exitcode = chan.recv_exit_status()
                outqueue.put("exit status: %s" %exitcode)
                #print('close s')
                #print(client.close())
                #time.sleep(0.01)
                #client.close()
                #print('close e')
                #time.sleep(0.05)
                break

def reader(outqueue):
    while True:
        while outqueue.qsize():
            try:
                data = outqueue.get()
                if data:
                    print(data)
            except Excetpiton as e:
                print(e)
                #continue
        #time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__=='__main__':
    pw = getpass.getpass()
    client = SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(WarningPolicy())
    #client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())

    if not start(client):
        #os._exit(0)
        sys.exit(0)

    outqueue = Queue()

    r = Thread(target=reader,args=(outqueue,))
    r.daemon = True
    r.start()

    t = Thread(target=check,args=(client,outqueue,))
    #t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    t.join()
```